# iOS, autolayout, dynamic columns

Tags: ios, autolayout

I need to implement a view like this in Portrait, and there are 6 elements in two columns and three rows:
[image: There are tow columns and three rows]

And if we rotate the screen to Landscape, we need to make all the elements in order like this:
[image: There are three columns and two rows]

I want to know is this possible to make it with autolayout? we need to support it on iOS 6.1 ++

Can anyone help ? 
Great thanks.

Comment: Why not use a collection view to accomplish this with a Vertical Flow Layout?

Comment: no , that is not possible with autolayout.

Comment: You can do this with auto layout (see my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499035/possible-to-transform-view-on-previous-view-controller-when-screen-orientation-c/24513954#24513954), but I think it would be better to use a collection view.

Comment: that is not possible to do with auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Interface Builder if you mean this. You can load/set different views (each can use AutoLayout) depending on device orientation **OR** use UICollectionView **OR** write AutoLayout in code for each case.